How to do a Material Select that not overflow his container
I developed a form that contains multiple fields: input or select.
The problem is that the container of this form has a well-defined height, and when I click on the select, it overflows.
I would like the select to occupy all the space it wants, but not to overflow with respect to the container of the form!
I have seen that when you click on a select and open the options it creates an overlay material.
This overlay does not belong to the select so I can't tell it to have a height of 100% because it takes up 100% of the entire page.
template
<div class="container">
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
      <mat-select>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
          {{food.viewValue}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>

style
.container {
   height:100px;
   overflow: hidden;
}

Has anyone ever encountered this? Thanks

Hi, can you please added some code then help you better way

to reproduce the problem you need a simple material select inside a container with a fixed height.
How do I make sure that when I open the select it doesn't overflow with respect to the container?

You can try the native HTML select mode of mat-select, which does not have overlay.
<div class="container">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Choose an option</mat-label>
    <select matNativeControl>
      <option value="" selected></option>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab" disabled>Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>

Stackblitz Demo

in your demo the options still overflow the container...
